# VBScript: I want to take the contents of a file and run an UPDATE statement using the contents of each line

Tags: vbscript

I have made a connection to a database. I want to take the contents of a file and run an UPDATE statement using the contents of each line.

### Database Connection

```
Option Explicit

Dim sDir : sDir = "\\Server1\Data"
Dim sCS  : sCS  = Join(Array( _
        "Provider=vfpoledb" _
      , "Data Source=" & sDir _
      , "Collating Sequence=general" _
), ";")
Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
oCN.Open sCS
oCN.Close
```

### File

```
STAD     1
SECA     2
..
```

### UPDATE Statement

For this line:

```
STAD     1
```

It would run:

```
UPDATE B_SNAME.DBF SET SN_ANALSYS = 1 WHERE SN_ACCOUNT = STAD
```

I am extremely new to VBScript and DBF. I would have no problem writing a little Bash script to do this on our Linux side but here I am lost.

Please can someone provide some information on how I could do it, or even an example (that would be awesome)? :-)

Comment: The file coming in, is it tab delimited?

Comment: @Fred There is a space (or multiple) between 1st word and 2nd word.

Comment: Are the fields in your data file file fixed-width?

Comment: @aphoria I can make it so that it is fixed 1 space between 1st word and 2nd word if it makes it easier.

Comment: That does make it easier as you can then `Split` the line into the two separate fields.

Comment: You could simplify your connection string definition like this `sCS  =  "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" & sDir & ";Collating Sequence=general;"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you separate the fields with one space or any single character (called a delimiter) you can use the split function to separate the fields.  You will end up with something like this (I have not tested this)

```
Dim strSQL
Dim strFilename
Dim sConnString
Dim scs
Dim oCN
Dim oCmd
Dim fso
Dim f


strFilename = "C:\Temp\MyFile.txt"

sConnString  = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=\\Server1\Data;Collating Sequence=general;"
strSQL = "UPDATE B_SNAME.DBF SET SN_ANALSYS = p1 WHERE SN_ACCOUNT = p2"

Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
oCN.Open sConnString

Dim oCmd
Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilename)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  sArray = Split(f.ReadLine, " ")
  oCmd.Parameters.Append oCmd.CreateParameter("p1", adChar, adParamInput, 4, sArray(1))
  oCmd.Parameters.Append oCmd.CreateParameter("p2", adChar, adParamInput, 8, sArray(0))
  oCmd.CommandText = strSQL
  oCmd.Execute
Loop

f.Close

If oCN.State = 1 Then oCN.Close

Set oCmd = Nothing
Set oCN = Nothing
```

Most lines are delimited with either tabs or commas but there is no reason why you cannot use a space as long as it does not appear in your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get a `Expected end of statement` on Line 1 Char 12? That would be the A in As? :-/

Comment: I removed the first `Dim oCmd` as well and left `Dim oCmd As ADODB.Command`, is that right or should I have left `Dim oCmd` and removed `Dim oCmd As ADODB.Command`? I get `Expected end of statement` on Line 19 Char 10 now.

Comment: That was another As, I have removed it from the answer.  Just copy my answer again. Let me know if you still get any errors.

Comment: But I get `Class not defined` without that As?

Comment: Is not the As causing that as all variable are variants in VB Script and you don't use `As [type]` in declarations.  Try changing `New ADODB.Command` to `CreateObject("ADODB.Command")`

Comment: `Object required: Server`. I guess I will do some searching ... :-)

Comment: `ADODB.Command: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another`. Is this code or database query problem?

Comment: What are the datatypes in the DataBase?

Comment: `SN_ACCOUNT` is Character(8) and `SN_ANALSYS` is Character(4).

Comment: Does this mean that my input file must be 4 characters and 8 characters (as it's not always the case, just 4 and 8 are the max), because I still get that same error ...

Comment: If it helps, I added `Option Explicit` and now get `Variable is undefined 'sConnString'`, but I see it at the top anyway?

Comment: No that's fine but change `adVarChar` to `adChar` Answer updated

Comment: Searched online all day, couldn't get this working :-/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to read the data file and get each field into a variable. This assumes your data file contains a four character account name followed by five spaces and then a number.

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim line
Dim sn_analsys
Dim sn_account
Dim dataFile
Set dataFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\SomeFolder\data.txt")
Do Until dataFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = dataFile.ReadLine
  sn_account = Left(line, 4)
  sn_analsys = Mid(line, 10)
  WScript.Echo "sn_account = " & sn_account
  WScript.Echo "sn_analsys = " & sn_analsys
  '
  ' Do whatever processing you need to do...
  '
Loop
dataFile.Close
```

If you change the data file to separate the fields by one space, you can use `Split` to get each field.

```
Dim line
Dim fields
Dim dataFile
Set dataFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\SomeFolder\data.txt")
Do Until dataFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = dataFile.ReadLine
  fields = Split(line)
  WScript.Echo "sn_account = " & fields(0)
  WScript.Echo "sn_analsys = " & fields(1)
  WScript.Echo
  '
  ' Do whatever processing you need to do...
  '
Loop
```